# Datetime conversion format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I converted the datetime from a format '2018-06-22T09:38:00.000-04:00'
to pandas datetime format

i tried to convert using pandas and got output but the output is

o/p: 2018-06-22 09:38:00-04:00

```
date = '2018-06-22T09:38:00.000-04:00'
dt = pd.to_datetime(date)
```

expected result: 2018-06-22 09:38

actual result:   2018-06-22 09:38:00-04:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is timestamps with timezones, so if convert to UTC by [`Timestamp.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html), times are changed:

```
date = '2018-06-22T09:38:00.000-04:00'
dt = pd.to_datetime(date).tz_convert(None)
print (dt)
2018-06-22 13:38:00
```

So possible solution is remove last 6 values in datetimes:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(date[:-6])
print (dt)
2018-06-22 09:38:00
```